# Writing to exec.Cmd.StdinPipe() doesn't do anything

Tags: go

I'm creating a new command with exec, obtaining the Stdin `io.WriteCloser` and writing to it as follows:

```golang
cmd := exec.Command(flag.Arg(0), flag.Args()[1:]...)
cmdInWriter, err := cmd.StdinPipe()

err = cmd.Start()

go func() {
    for {
        var c string
        _, err = fmt.Scanln(&c)
        written, err := io.WriteString(cmdInWriter, c)
        fmt.Println(written) // prints 4, if c is "help"
    }
}()
```

However, this doesn't seem to actually write to the program.

- `flag.Arg(0)` = java
- `flag.Args()[1:]...` = an array of arguments passed to the java program

I tested it with [another program](https://hasteb.in/ojiconik.go) I quickly made (the previous list does not apply there) and the string was again not being written. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the linefeed. When you read a string using Scanln, the resulting string does not have the linefeed at the end:

```
 written, err := fmt.Fprintln(cmdInWriter, c)
```

Comment: Ahhh, thanks so much! I've been stuck at this all day :P